# Merging data in d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm Pythonista and trying to learn d3.js (smile).

I have a server with a socket. My page subscribes to it.
Server sends updates as JSON `'[["id0", 0.38], ["id1", 0.70], ["id8", 0.71]]'`.
I wrote the following simple page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WebSockets</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
    <script>
      var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9999/updates");
      ws.onmessage = function(message)
      {
        var my_data = JSON.parse(message.data);
        var dd = d3.selectAll("#messages")
          .append("div")
          .selectAll("div")
          .data(my_data)
          .enter()
          .append("div")
          .attr("id",function(d){return d[0];})
          .text(function(d){return d[1];})
      }
    </script>
    <div id='messages'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works fine! WS receives the data. In the `div#messages` it creates a new `div`. And then places data from msg into the `div#id*`. So, after many iteration I have:

```
...
<div id="messages">
  <div>
    <div id="id0">0.83</div>
    <div id="id1">0.06</div>
    <div id="id2">0.33</div>
  </div>
  <div> 
    ... 
  </div>
  <div> 
    ... 
  </div>
  ...
</div>
...
```

---

How to modify the code to make it work like this:

**Having**

```
...
<div id='messages'>
  <div id='id0'>0.25</div>
  <div id='id1'>0.05</div>
  <div id='id2'>0.25</div>
</div>
...
```

**Recieve**

```
'[["id0", 0.38], ["id1", 0.70], ["id8", 0.71]]'
```

**Get in result**

```
...
<div id='messages'>
  <div id='id0'>0.38</div>
  <div id='id1'>0.70</div>
  <div id='id2'>0.25</div>
  <div id='id8'>0.71</div>
</div>
...
```

**I mean "if given id in #messages then update it; else append it to the end"**.

I could do this with loops, but doc says that it shall be done with `enter()` and `exit()`..

It seems that in these articles ([circle](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/circle.html), [join](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)) is written how to do that.
The problem is that I do not understand ideas  of data synchronization in these articles at all.
I hope that the code will help me understand this.

---

**PS:** I do all the logic in Python, however, I must show data on the page with minimal redrawing. And everyone says that d3 - is very easy and convenient. I read the docs and it seems that d3 is good framework, but I have some troubles with fundamentals.

---

**PPS:** If data should be transmitted in other way - there is no problem.

---

---

**UPDATE**

With the help of console, I found, that

```
d3.select("#messages")
  .select("div")
  .selectAll("div")
  .data([["id0",0]], function(d){return d[0];})
  .enter()
```

gives me array `[null]`

```
d3.select("#messages")
  .select("div")
  .selectAll("div")
  .data([["id0",0]], function(d){return d[0];})
```

gives me array `[HTMLDivElement]` with `HTMLDivElement.__data__ == ["id0",0]`

and

```
d3.select("#messages")
  .select("div")
  .selectAll("div")
  .data([["id0",0]], function(d){return d[0];})
  .exit()
```

gives  `[null, HTMLDivElement, HTMLDivElement]` with `"id1"` and `"id2"` in `HTMLDivElement.__data__[0]` respectively.

**Any idea What next?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this seems to work..
but what does it really do?

```
var my_data = JSON.parse(message.data);
var my_selection = d3.selectAll("#messages")
  .selectAll("div")
  .data(my_data, function(d){return d[0];})
my_selection
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("id",function(d){return d[0];})
my_selection
  .text(function(d){return d[1];})
```

If nobody can answer, may be somebody can explain?

Comment: Since it's been a while, do you understand what the code does or would you still like an explanation?

Comment: @arigold yes, I do. But if you can edit my answer with more info, I think it would be good for community.

Comment: I was thinking of the clearest & most concise way of putting it and couldn't do better than [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/).