# Strange "initial" values in d3.js

Tags: javascript, css, background, styles, d3.js

By executing code that is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593245/merging-data-in-d3-js) (`d3.select(..).append("div")`), I get `div`s with such style properties:

```
<div id="id6" 
  style="
    background-image: initial; 
    background-attachment: initial; 
    background-origin: initial; 
    background-clip: initial; 
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    background-position: initial initial; 
    background-repeat: initial initial; ">
5
</div>
```

**Questions:**

1. a) Where does `initial` comes from? b) Is it possible to redefine "defaults"?
2. Is it Ok that d3 litters in the properties with [unnecessary values](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#initial0)?
3. Chrome says that `background-position: initial initial;` and 
           `background-repeat: initial initial;` are `Invalid property value`s. Is it a bug of d3? How can we deal with this error?

Comment: I'm not aware of d3 doing anything like this. The "initial" values must be coming from somewhere else. What exactly is the code that produces this?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff There is a link in the first paragraph of the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with D3, but with the implicit nature of CSS. When you specify the CSS [background property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#propdef-background), you are actually specifying multiple properties in shorthand. For example,

```
background: url(chess.png) gray 50% repeat fixed;
```

Is actually shorthand for

```
background-image: url(chess.png);
background-color: gray;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

So, when you set the style "background", your browser automatically expands this shorthand to the full form. That's why you see all of these additional styles; they represent the [computed values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/computed_value).

Comment: Ok. If all this stuff is maded with browser, why it says that some properties are invalid?

Comment: +if i add something like `<style> div {background-position:inherit;}</style>` in head, I still have `background-position: initial initial;` in generated divs.